# Is Roslyn the right tool for a compile-time Expression checking?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I have a toolkit that has many methods often taking `Expression<Func<T,TProperty>>` as parameters. Some can be single-level only (`o=>o.Name`), while some can be multi-level (`o=>o.EmployeeData.Address.Street`).

I want to develop something (MSBuild Task? Visual Studio Plugin? hopefully the first) that reads all the user's .cs files, and gives build errors if the given parameter is not a property-expression (but something like `o=>o.Contains("foo")`), or if a multi-level expression is given where only a single-level is allowed.

I tried looking at compiled IL code first but since the expression trees are a C# compiler "trick", in IL all I see is creating expression instances and such, and while I *could* check each if only MemberExpressions (and the correct number of them) are created, it is not so great.

Then Roslyn came to my mind. **Is it possible to write something like this with Roslyn?**

Comment: Why do you need to enforce these constraints?

Comment: because the stuff I do in these methods (property change handling, error checking, etc) only make sense on property expressions

Comment: and because this felt like an interesting thing to do :)

Comment: This should be pretty easy to do as a Roslyn VS plugin. You'll even get nice squiggly lines.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Could you point me towards what classes should I be looking for in Roslyn? I have never used Roslyn before... Also, can it be done in a MSBuild Task? I find those much easier to work with then plugins...

Comment: My experiments are on [my github](https://github.com/CodesInChaos/Roslyn). There is a way to create standalone roslyn applications, but I didn't look into the details.

Comment: maybe this article can help you on the way, it implements some checking for use of Count() == 1 and reports its as an issue http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/02/06/implementing-a-code-action-using-roslyn.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I think Roslyn and its code issues are exactly the right tool for this. With them, you can analyze the code while you type and create errors (or warnings) that are shown as other errors in Visual Studio.

I have tried to create such code issue:

```
[ExportSyntaxNodeCodeIssueProvider("PropertyExpressionCodeIssue", LanguageNames.CSharp, typeof(InvocationExpressionSyntax))]
class PropertyExpressionCodeIssueProvider : ICodeIssueProvider
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public PropertyExpressionCodeIssueProvider()
    {}

    public IEnumerable<CodeIssue> GetIssues(IDocument document, CommonSyntaxNode node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var invocation = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)node;

        var semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModel(cancellationToken);

        var semanticInfo = semanticModel.GetSemanticInfo(invocation, cancellationToken);

        var methodSymbol = (MethodSymbol)semanticInfo.Symbol;

        if (methodSymbol == null)
            yield break;

        var attributes = methodSymbol.GetAttributes();

        if (!attributes.Any(a => a.AttributeClass.Name == "PropertyExpressionAttribute"))
            yield break;

        var arguments = invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments;
        foreach (var argument in arguments)
        {
            var lambdaExpression = argument.Expression as SimpleLambdaExpressionSyntax;
            if (lambdaExpression == null)
                continue;

            var parameter = lambdaExpression.Parameter;
            var memberAccess = lambdaExpression.Body as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
            if (memberAccess != null)
            {
                var objectIdentifierSyntax = memberAccess.Expression as IdentifierNameSyntax;

                if (objectIdentifierSyntax != null
                    && objectIdentifierSyntax.PlainName == parameter.Identifier.ValueText
                    && semanticModel.GetSemanticInfo(memberAccess, cancellationToken).Symbol is PropertySymbol)
                    continue;
            }

            yield return
                new CodeIssue(
                    CodeIssue.Severity.Error, argument.Span,
                    string.Format("Has to be simple property access of '{0}'", parameter.Identifier.ValueText));
        }
    }

    #region Unimplemented ICodeIssueProvider members

    public IEnumerable<CodeIssue> GetIssues(IDocument document, CommonSyntaxToken token, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<CodeIssue> GetIssues(IDocument document, CommonSyntaxTrivia trivia, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The usage would be like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
class PropertyExpressionAttribute : Attribute
{ }

…

[PropertyExpression]
static void Foo<T>(Expression<Func<SomeType, T>> expr)
{ }

…

Foo(x => x.P);   // OK
Foo(x => x.M()); // error
Foo(x => 42);    // error
```

The code above has several issues:

1. It's completely unoptimized.
2. It probably needs some more error checking.
3. **It does not work.** At least in the current CTP. The expression `semanticModel.GetSemanticInfo(memberAccess, cancellationToken).Symbol` near the end always returns `null`. This is because semantics of expressions trees is among [the currently unimplemented features](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/roslyn/thread/f5adeaf0-49d0-42dc-861b-0f6ffd731825).

Comment: Roslyn came out with a new CTP. I guess it'd be good time to try this again then? :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's totally possible. The problem is Roslyn doesn't yet support all language constructs yet, so you might run into some unsupported stuff. Expression trees are unsupported in that Roslyn cannot compile code that generates expressions, but you should be able to get far enough to make some things work.

At a high level, if you wanted to implement this as an MSBuild task, in your build task you could call `Roslyn.Services.Workspace.LoadSolution` or `Roslyn.Services.Workspace.LoadStandaloneProject`. You'd then walk through the syntax trees looking for mentions of your various methods, and then bind them to make sure it's actually the method you think you're calling. From there, you could find the lambda syntax nodes, and perform whatever syntax/semantic analysis you want from there.

There are a few sample projects in the CTP you might find useful, such as the `RFxCopConsoleCS` project, which implements a simple FxCop-style rule in Roslyn.

I should also mention that the parser is complete for Roslyn, so the more you can do without semantic information, the better.